# Cross Domain class constraints

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'm new to Grails and I have two domain classes like this:

```
class User {    
    String username
    String password

    static hasMany = ['boards':Board]
    static belongsTo = ['belongsToBoard':Board]
}

class Board {
    String message
    boolean starred
}
```

Now I want the constraints like "`User` can have a `board` with `message` being unique"(Note that I don't want `Board` to be unique, but for each `User`, the `message` should be unique. Example:

```
User : batman
Board: test,test (messages)
```

is not valid, where as:

```
User: batman
Board: test

User: batgirl
Board: test
```

is valid one.

Is it possible to do so in the grails `constraints` block? If not how should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `belongsTo` property is unusual - if this is a one-many, i.e. a User has many Boards, then the `belongsTo` goes on the Board side. This enables cascaded deletes and also only uses two tables; if the relationship isn't bidirectional you get a third to manage the relationship. If it's a many-to-many then you're missing the `hasMany` in Board.

If it is a one-many and you put this in Board

```
static belongsTo = [user: User]
```

then you can put a 2-column unique constraint in Board:

```
static constraints = {
   message unique: 'user'
}
```

This is described in the docs on the right in the "Constraints" section under "unique".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is my use-case, User can have their own boards (1-many) and also User can belong to board (in this case, User doesnt owns the board, but belongs to the board, which other user have created.